# Issue: When running npm start in the directory C:\Users\Arzo\OneDrive\Documents\reract start\login\signup,

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

```
PS C:\Users\Arzo\OneDrive\Documents\reract start\login\signup> npm start
> signup@0.1.0 start
> node index.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader: 1080

throw err;

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Arzo\OneDrive\Documents\reract start\login\signup\index.js'

at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader: 1077:15)

at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader: 922:27)

at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)

at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {

code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

requireStack: []



}

Node.js v18.16.1
```

what should  be done.. index.js file is in the folder but it is unable to run..directory is already selected

Comment: you need to attach your package.json script also